# Can ´t detect UItouch

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, uitouch

I have a large image (1024, 1496) as a background image of my layer.So I started to show the button of the image. 
In the time of application I show the top of the image, and some CCSprites.

```
id move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0,-746)];
[layer runAction:move];
```

My problem is that I can't detect touch on the CCSrites because their position stay the same  ex. (20, 1200), and the UITouch between the (1024,746).

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

for(UITouch * touch in  [event allTouches]){ 

    for (CCSprite *book in books) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([book boundingBox], location)) 
            NSLog(@"Touch");
        else{
             NSLog(@"NO Touch");            }
    }
```

}

}

Any idea how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the sprite touch to world coordinates. You can do this with your own method by calculating the screen position based on zooming and sprite size, or use methods within Cocos to convert to world coordinates. I tend to do the former.